# Javascript Arrays - Checking two arrays of objects for same contents, ignoring order

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison, compare

I have two JavaScript arrays (`A` and `B`) that contain objects that I created. I want to check that all the objects in array `A` are contained in array `B`, but not necessarily in the same order.

What is the best way to do this?

Edit:

They are all actual objects, not primitives, so I will need to compare their contents and structure as well (maybe using something like `JSON.stringify`).

I want to do this because I'm learning Test-Driven Development, and I want to test functions that return lists of objects. I need to test whether the returned lists have the expected objects in them or not (order doesn't matter in this case).

Comment: Are they primitives such as `true`, `false`, `23` or actual objects? Also can you explain why you want to do this? There may be a better way.

Comment: Edited question for clarification.

Comment: Why not first sort and then use JSON.stringify to compare

Comment: Actually you can compare objects by reference.

Comment: How complex are these objects you're comparing?  Do they have characteristics you're going to need to check as well (methods, etc)?

Comment: @g.d.d.c - That's a good point. If that is the case a deep compare may be the only way.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - It's good practice for recursive processing that's for sure.  It can take some time though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Usage:** `isEqArrays(arr1, arr2)`

```
//
// Array comparsion
//

function inArray(array, el) {
  for ( var i = array.length; i--; ) {
    if ( array[i] === el ) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isEqArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  if ( arr1.length !== arr2.length ) {
    return false;
  }
  for ( var i = arr1.length; i--; ) {
    if ( !inArray( arr2, arr1[i] ) ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Is this faster than @ChaosPandion's solution?

Comment: it's cross browser. Chaos's isn't. He uses language features which are not well-supported yet.

Comment: This code doesn't work: `isEqArrays([0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1])` returns `true`.

Answer (score 4):

With ES6 you could use every and some (and length).

```
let A = [1, 2, 3];
let B = [2, 3, 1];

// all objects in A are contained in B (A ⊆ B)
// you can compare a <-> b however you'd like (here just `a === b`)
let AsubB = A.every(a => B.some(b => a === b));

// A and B are the same length
let sameLength = A.length === B.length;

// their contents are as equal as previously tested:
let equal = AsubB && sameLength;
```

Comment: Checking for containment, even when you use both directions, does not account for multiple equal elements; e.g., consider [1,2,3,3] and [1,2,2,3].

Comment: for checking two object properties it's fine; moreover in the question is not requested to check for repeats. I used it with an object containing dates from and to and works nice.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the simplest method if not the slowest.

```
var o = { PropA: 1, PropB: 2 };
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, o];
var b = [2, 3, 4, 1];

var c = a.filter(function(value, index, obj) {
    return b.indexOf(value) > -1;
});

if (c.length !== a.length) {
    throw new Error("Array b is missing some elements!");
}
```

`indexOf` will only check that they refer to the same object. If you want to check value equivalence you will have to do a deep compare of the properties or use `JSON.stringify` as you mention in your question.

Comment: Does `.indexOf` check for object equivalency too? As in, if I make an `o2 = { PropA: 2, PropB: 2}` and put it in `b`, would it return something other than `-1`?

Comment: As with the other answer, this returns a false positive for `[0, 1, 1]` and `[0, 0, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple & Elegant

```
function isEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    return arr1.every(x => arr2.includes(x));
}
```

If duplication is important, use this

```
function isEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    arr1.sort();
    arr2.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `isEqual([0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1])` returns true...

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seem more difficult than I thought and I need to code it myself. Please check my solution:

```js
//usage
const arr1 = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 1
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  },
];
const arr2 = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 1
  },
];
alert(compareTwoArray(arr1, arr2));

function compareTwoArray(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length != arr2.length || arr1.length == arr2.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  //clone arr to process
  let arr01 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1));
  let arr02 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2));
  for (let i = (arr01.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    for (let j = (arr02.length - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
      if (JSON.stringify(arr01[i]) === JSON.stringify(arr02[j])) {
        arr01.splice(i, 1);
        arr02.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  if (arr01.length == 0 && arr02.length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is for array of values only:

```js
//usage
alert(compareTwoArray([0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]));

function compareTwoArray(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length != arr2.length || arr1.length == arr2.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  //clone arr to process
  let arr01 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1));
  let arr02 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2));
  for (let i = (arr01.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    for (let j = (arr01.length - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
      if (arr01[i] == arr02[j]) {
        //remove duplicate item from both array
        arr01.splice(i, 1);
        arr02.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  if (arr01.length == 0 && arr02.length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: is it working with actual objects, not primitives?

Comment: @MarcC I think you need to add code to compare two object instead of if (arr01[i] == arr02[j]) and then it can be work on arrays of objects

Comment: The question mentioned object comparison so your solution does not answer the question. You have to consider nested objects as well (ie. a tree of objects).

Comment: @MarcC oh right! I just updated my answer for arrays of objects

Comment: Good, your approach is generating a lot of new objects and strings but is doing the job.
I would have opted for a recursive in-place comparison.