# How to make a deep comparison of unordered arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'd like compare two arrays which not necessary orderly. I tried to use ImmutableJS (fromJS), but it dont work with a unordered arrays. Please, look at example arrays which must be equals

First array

```
[
        {
            Jnam: 'processor',
            Ci: 'New York',
        },
        {
            Jnam: 'keyboard',
            Ci: 'Washington',
        },
        {
            Jnam: 'display',
            Ci: 'Seattle',
        },
]
```

Second

```
[
        {
            Jnam: 'keyboard',
            Ci: 'Washington',
        },
        {
            Jnam: 'processor',
            Ci: 'New York',
        },
        {
            Ci: 'Seattle',
            Jnam: 'display',
        },
]
```

Could you answer me what you do in that situations?

Comment: Why not just sort them both first?

Comment: and what is the wanted result? just `true` or `false`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Arrays - Checking two arrays of objects for same contents, ignoring order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243275/javascript-arrays-checking-two-arrays-of-objects-for-same-contents-ignoring-o)

Comment: @RobAnthony Sort will be the last solution, that i'll choose. This array is set of objects and i'd like to work with these objects like mathematical objects, not js-object. Besides, how will i be sort these objects, if they haven't key, that according to which being sort?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes

Comment: @GabrielBleu The solution presented there works only with primitives. It can be converted into objects, but perhaps there is a more declarative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a hash table with the keys as first property and the values as second property and check the second array with it.

If hash is found decrement hash to check the exact count.

```js
function getKeyValue(object) {
    var keys = Object.keys(object).sort();

    return { key: keys.join('|'), value: keys.map(function (k) { return object[k]; }).join('|') };
}

var first = [{ Jnam: 'processor', Ci: 'New York', }, { Jnam: 'keyboard', Ci: 'Washington' }, { Jnam: 'display', Ci: 'Seattle' }],
    second = [{ Jnam: 'keyboard', Ci: 'Washington', }, { Jnam: 'processor', Ci: 'New York' }, { Ci: 'Seattle', Jnam: 'display' }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    count = 0,
    result;

first.forEach(function (o) {
    var kv = getKeyValue(o);
    hash[kv.key] = hash[kv.key] || {};
    hash[kv.key][kv.value] = (hash[kv.key][kv.value] || 0) + 1;
    count++;
});

result = second.every(function (o) {
    var kv = getKeyValue(o);
    count--;
    if (hash[kv.key] && hash[kv.key][kv.value]) {
        hash[kv.key][kv.value]--;
        return true;
    }
}) && !count;

console.log(result);
console.log(hash);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It's interesting solution. Thank a lot!